# querySelector to addEventListener with function parameter

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, queryselector

I try to pass a variable **sel1** as parameter of function **fxIn**. 
But event is not trigger, since this get no error in console, I don`t know what is going on.

```
var sel1 = window.document.querySelector('#item1')
sel1.addEventListener('mouseover', fxIn(sel1))
sel1.addEventListener('mouseout', fxOut(sel1))
```

the functions are:

```
// change bg color
function fxIn(selectorX){
    selectorX.style.background = 'red'
}

// reset bg color
function fxOut(){
    selectorX.style.background = ''
}
```

Why this don`t work? the output expect is to have background color changed when mouse is over a div tag.

Comment: you're calling `fxIn` and `fxOut` in your callback, instead you need to pass the uncalled function into `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the function inside of an anonymous function.

```
sel1.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ fxIn(sel1) })
```

Though you do not need to pass the same object on which you are attaching the event. You can simply use `this` to refer the object directly:

```js
var sel1 = window.document.querySelector('#item1')
sel1.addEventListener('mouseover', fxIn);
sel1.addEventListener('mouseout', fxOut);


// change bg color
function fxIn(){
    this.style.background = 'red'
}

// reset bg color
function fxOut(){
    this.style.background = ''
}
```

```css
#item1{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="item1">Container</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `addEventListener` is expected to be a function, which can then be called by JS when the event occurs. You're calling your function (which returns `undefined`), so, you're actually passing `undefined` as the second argument.

One possible solution would be to make your `fxIn` and `fxOut` return a function so that you can use it in the context of `addEventListener` like so:

```js
const fxIn = selectorX => e => selectorX.style.background = 'red';
const fxOut = selectorX => e => selectorX.style.background = '';

const sel1 = window.document.querySelector('#item1')
sel1.addEventListener('mouseover', fxIn(sel1));
sel1.addEventListener('mouseout', fxOut(sel1));
```

```html
<p id="item1">Item 1</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the other others have the key points covered, here's an alternative solution that uses `classList` to toggle classes to the element.

```js
const sel1 = document.querySelector('#item1');

function toggle() {
  this.classList.toggle('red');
}

sel1.addEventListener('mouseover', toggle);
sel1.addEventListener('mouseout', toggle);
```

```css
#item1 { width: 200px; height: 200px; }
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="item1">Container</div>
```

Comment: :-) I've got a present for you. [`classList` has a `toggle()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods)

Comment: Haha. I'd completely forgotten @Kaiido.